# Performance of HashSet<T> and Linq queries

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-objects, hashset

During last week I received some code and was asked to improve the performance. So started with the job, but soon I saw that they use a lot of `HashSet<T>` objects, to store big collections of objects (between 10000 to more than 100000 objects). In the code they use `HashSet<T>` for performance reasons.

The only thing that they do is populate the HashSet with objects and then us some Linq to execute queries between multiple collections. Most of the queries are joining 1 or n HashSet, or retrieving specific object(s) from the collection with `First()` or `Where()`.

I'm wondering if we gain any performance advantage compared to a normal `List<T>`?  Because all the Linq extension methods they use in code are written for `IEnumerable<T>`.

On the internet a lot of articles say that List would be faster, but some say that HashSet handles huge collections much better than List.

Hope that someone can give me more advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you easily write a test comparing the performance of both of these?

Comment: I would also note that a HashSet isn't ordered - taking its `First` element is wrong, unless you need an arbitrary element, or have already filtered all but one element.

Comment: Your approach is very unproductive.  Use a profiler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use just LINQ queries, you don't get any perf advantage, since you are just enumerating through the entire collection. In fact, it could be that `List<T>` is better performance because of the contiguous internal storage.

To get the perf benefit of a `HashSet<T>`, you need to use the `ISet<T>` methods, ideally with another `HashSet<T>` since, looking at the code, it is optimized for this case. Further, operations will only be faster which take advantage of the member objects' hash codes, like equality testing, since the performance of `HashSet<T>` is based on the O(1) performance characteristic of hash lookups. Operations which don't make use of the members' hash codes, like filtering on a member property vs. the members themselves, will need to be an O(N) operation, making it the same as a `List<T>`.